# Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Getting following Exception while clicking "Create Records" button:

```
   System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user: : [RecordTypeId]
```

I have suspect on selected users dont have access to record typesAnyone please help me to achive this functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I think it would be preferable if you did not delete and then repost this question, since I and others had already engaged in seeking clarification on your original post.

As far as I can tell, the error here doesn't really have anything to do with your code as such, and it is certainly not related to the distinction between Visualforce and Lightning implementations. It has to do with the configuration of your Profiles and with the business logic by which you are selecting record types for the records you are creating.

You have defined extensive business logic for selecting available record types based upon specific data attributes in the constructor `CaseAssociatedSerExc()`. However, some of the users who are available to have these records assigned to them do not have those record types active for them, resulting in your `DMLException` when you attempt to perform the insert.

Since the record types you make available for selection are dictated by data attributes on the Case, it would make sense if you similarly limited the available users to whom you may assign each `Service_Excellence__c` to specific groups - whether that means actual Groups, Profiles, Roles, or what have you - for whom those record types are relevant, and ensure that those users have access to the record types involved in their Profiles.

I don't see this as a problem caused by a bug in your code. It's really more of a business logic and architecture issue that you need to figure out how to address, and then write a relatively small amount of additional code to filter the available User records appropriately for that custom lookup component you are using.

Comment: I was astonished and disappointed to see this being reposted. Thanks David for your patience and bringing this to attention.

Comment: this user has a habit of doing this on the forum, as well as deleting poorly received questions and reposting and based on the 2 year post history seems to strongly rely on the community to get things done. Unfortunately, the quality of the OP's questions has not really increased even after haven been told on numerous occasions why his posts are being downvoted and what he should do and learn to troubleshoot/debug code he is attempting to write =(

Comment: @glls can you please whats the wrong in this question. whenever I stuck,i will post it.. but i never post the questions like community memebers to achieve that functionality. whenever I posted question you will come and say some thing and go,,, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249765/server-side-returns-no-results/249783?noredirect=1#comment379872_249783... for this one i deleted and repost it.Im really say sorry to david reed & christian.They already engaged for that question

Comment: @glls Can you please show me what are those questions. how much you helped on that. I Got so many negative points also I kept it. i lost nearly 2k points. i never deleted those questions. check my profile you will come to know...

Comment: please dont use comments for extended discussions...

Comment: @AnnappaPH That's quite hyperbolic. You have never lost more than 200 points in a day and your cumulative negative points look to be a far cry short of 2000. That said, I think a lot of the reason you get down votes is that your posts do not demonstrate a ton of debugging effort on your part, and come across as just a code dump where you don't put thought into how to make the post useful to anyone but yourself. The community here is about building a knowledge base that will be useful for others.