# server side returns no results

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Able to pass lightning component values to server side. But passed Ids are not working in server side

For ex:  caseIDStr contains values.Please check below image

[image]

But this is not building below query

```
   clist=[Select Id, 
CaseNumber,GSS_Business_unit__c,GSS_Support_Level__c,owner.Name from Case 
     where Id IN:caseIDStr];
```

Instead of caseIDStr IF i Hardcode Ids ,i will get the reults

I suspect that probelm caseIDStr, why its breaking

VFPAGE:

```
 <apex:page standardController="case" extensions="Gss_CsHelathCheckExtension"  
 recordsetVar="lstAllUserData" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
      <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
<apex:includeLightning />
<div id="lightning" />
  <script>
// alert(typeof "{!lstSelUserDataIds}");
   var  myList = '{!lstSelUserDataIds}';
   var tempmylist = myList.split(',');
//alert(typeof tempmylist);
    $Lightning.use("c:Gss_CloneSkillsToApp", function(){
        $Lightning.createComponent(
            "c:Gss_CaseHealthCheck",
            {"caselist" : tempmylist},
            "lightning",
            function(cmp){});
    });
</script>
```

controller:

```
public class Gss_CsHelathCheckExtension {
ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;
public String[] lstSelUserDataIds{get; set;}
public Gss_CsHelathCheckExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController)
{
    system.debug('---constructor--');
    this.setCon =standardController;
    lstSelUserDataIds = new String[]{};
        for(case selectedRec : (List<case>)setCon.getSelected())
    {
        lstSelUserDataIds.add(selectedRec.id);
        system.debug('---lstSelUserDataIds--'+lstSelUserDataIds);
    }
}
```

}

Component:

```
<!-- caselist value from vf page
 <aura:attribute name="caselist" type="String[]"/>
```

Js side:

```
var action=component.get("c.getCaseDetails");
action.setParams({
     "caseIDStr":component.get("v.caselist"),
});
action.setCallback(this,function(response) {
   var state=response.getState();
   if(state==='SUCCESS'){
       component.set("v.caseSerExcList",response.getReturnValue());
   }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Server side:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<object> getCaseDetails(String [] caseIDStr){
 system.debug('caseIDStr---->'+caseIDStr);
  //for this query id values are not passing.If I do hardcode it will work
   if(!caseIDStr.isEmpty()){
        clist=[Select Id, 
CaseNumber,GSS_Business_unit__c,GSS_Support_Level__c,owner.Name from Case 
     where Id IN:caseIDStr];
    }
    system.debug('clist --->'+clist);

    for(Case c: clist ){
        caseSerExcList.add(new CaseAssociatedSerExc(c));
    }
    system.debug('caseSerExcList--->'+caseSerExcList);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visualforce's default formatting for a list of strings is in the form:

```
[value1,value2]
```

Which means your code looks like this:

```
var  myList = '[value1,value2]';
```

So when you split it, you get an array that looks like this:

```
var tempmylist = ['[value1','value2]'];
```

Which is what ultimately gives you that bizarre value in your Lightning Component's controller.

Instead, serialize the list as JSON initially and present that to your script:

```
public String lstSelUserDataIds{get; set;}
```

...

```
lstSelUserDataIds = JSON.serialize(dataIds);
```

...

```
// DO NOT USE QUOTES HERE //
var myList = {!lstSelUserDataIds}; 
$Lightning.use("c:Gss_CloneSkillsToApp", function(){
    $Lightning.createComponent(
        "c:Gss_CaseHealthCheck",
        { caselist : myList },
        "lightning",
        function(cmp){});
});
```

Comment: Problem is : If I remove   quotes  myList = {!lstSelUserDataIds} component  isnot loading.Value will not pass from vf page to Lightning components. If I add it in quote value will pass from vf page to lightning components

Comment: still that issue is present. If I pass myList  values in quotes.still same issue present

Comment: @AnnappaPH You need to json serialize, it should be a Srting instead of Dtring[].

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in a comment on your [previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249750/system-string-exceptioninvalid-ids), the debug log clearly shows that what is reaching your Apex controller *is not a List of Ids*. It is a `List` containing exactly one String, whose value is the literal text `'[5001k..., 5001k...]'`.

You can demonstrate this for yourself just by running in the Developer Console

```
System.debug(new List<String>{ '001', '002' });
```

which yields

> 23:00:23:004 USER_DEBUG [1]|DEBUG|(001, 002)

Note that *there are no square brackets* - Apex does not use square brackets when debugging a `List`.

<s>The code that populates `v.caselist` in your JavaScript controller is at fault here.</s> I was mistaken, sfdcfox identified the root cause in your Lightning Out code.

The contents of your attribute are *not* what you think they are, and you need to work through your code to determine why.

Comment: I am happy to accept u r suggestion..I don't think it will be not the ans for my question..I am  cross verifying it.. and I mentioned it in comments my debug results  and root causes

Comment: I missed the root cause. sfdcfox found it.